# How to get the url of a page in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

How to get the url of a page in OpenERP?

User is using OpenERP. I have a button on one web page. The button's action function is action_go() (code provided). When I click on a button, the code opens a new web page in a new tab in browser. Now, I want, in the button action handler function, action_go(), to read current IP address so I can make the new url to launch it with the button (code for that url provided)

Here is the code that uses url:

```
class mrp_bom_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

    def action_go(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        bom_obj = self.pool.get('mrp.bom')
                ip_address = '127.0.0.1:8069'
        url = 'http://' + ip_address + '/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=mrp.bom&menu_id=448&action=565'
        for bom_line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if bom_line.product_id.default_code > '300':
                bom_ids = bom_obj.search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', bom_line.product_id.id)], context=context)
                if bom_ids:
                                        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 
                        'res_model': 'ir.actions.act_url',
                        # 'url':'http://127.0.0.1:8069/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=mrp.bom&action=452' % bom_ids[0] , 
                                                'url':url % bom_ids[0] , 
                        'nodestroy': True, 
                        'target': 'new_tab'}

        return True
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. What's the IP address for? And why would it change ?

Comment: Users will have a website to access OpenERP. I need that current url or IP address from the browser to use it to launch another page as written in code (return statement). Please let me know if this is clear.

Comment: "A website to access OpenERP" -> An external website that will redirect them to openerp ? And I stlil don't understand what you are trying to do here. Can you be more specific and give full use case ?

Comment: User is using OpenERP. I have a button on one web page. The button's action function is action_go() (code provided). When I click on a button, the code opens a new web page in a new tab in browser. Now, I want, in the button action handler function, action_go(), to read current IP address so I can make the new url to launch it with the button (code for that url provided)

Comment: If the user is not going to a different URL, you can just that part out I guess, such as: '/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=mrp.bom&menu_id=448&action=565'. The browser will take care of the protocol and the domain itself

Comment: By the way, you should edit your description to include the extra information you added for other users. They won't necessarily read the comments

Comment: You guess is correct. But I still want to know if there is a method to get current url while navigating through OpenERP system. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. But I don't know the actual function in OpenERP

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar requirement where the button in the tree view redirects to another url outside openerp. But the problem is that the button can be clicked only once, if I need to click it again, then i have to refresh my page. Is this an odoo issue or any peculiarity with this return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is not going to a different server, you can just leave that part out I guess, such as: `'/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=mrp.bom&menu_id=448&action=565'`. The browser will take care of the protocol and the domain itself